# How to do pagination on Columns instead of Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

I am currently doing a `Gridview` and I'd like to have pagination on Columns instead of Rows.

For instance, I've a set of dates records `10/11/2016`, `11/11/2016`, `12/11/2016`, `13/11/2016` and I only want to show 2 dates per page.

[image: FirstPage]

Then when I click on next page, I will get this.

[image: SecondPage]

Is it accomplishable to have paging on `col` instead of `row` ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. Server side will be complex with regards to client side pagination. For server side you will need to override pagination control to render pages as per your column logic and to pass it back during postpack,
in gridview row databound event you can hide columns based on these passed value.